# Prevent "Hover Zoom" plugin from displaying zoomed img (or adding class to img div)

Tags: css, image, resize, hover, zooming

The Hover Zoom chrome ext. loads the original sized pic upon hover.

For my images, I resized inside css because it saves me the photoshop cropping step. 
< img src='..images/title.jpg' width='300px' height='auto'/>

But for users who use Hover Zoom, a new class is added to the  and the original size will be loaded.

Is there anyone way to prevent hover zoom from working? while keeping the css resize. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add css like this:

```
img {
        width:250px;
        height:61px;
      }
img:hover {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the answer and it did not work for my scenario. In my case, I forcefully hide the element - though the id is subject to change, etc. Too bad there is not a better way (that I found)

```
#hzImg {
    display: none !important;
}
```